# Bypass Proxy WebServices Call (Apache CXF/Azure)

Tags: java, azure, web-services, cxf, jax-ws

First of all a little bit of context. We have application in Azure and running on Java/Tomcat. We use SOAP webservices using Apache CXF. We have an interfacing application, who are in the process of migrating to Azure. So for integration tests, they provided us with their Azure URL that we need to connect to. The code uses MSAL4J too.

But every time we try to connect to their URL we are getting the error:

```
Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable"
```

The code is written currently like:

```
public void init() throws Exception {
    
    // Set the security handler
    getService().setHandlerResolver(new HandlerResolverImpl());

    // Setting endpoint URL and timeout...
    getBindingProvider().getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout", connectTimeout);
    getBindingProvider().getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.connectionTimeout", connectTimeout);
    getBindingProvider().getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endPointUrl);

    Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    headers.put("Content-Type", Collections.singletonList("application/soap+xml"));
    headers.put(Message.ENCODING, Collections.singletonList("UTF-8"));

    // Get the Azure Access Token
    String token = null;

    try {

        getLogger().debug("Acquiring Token for Azure Auth.");

        IClientCredential iClientCredential = ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(AppInit.getProperty("m3.clientSecret"));

        ConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(AppInit.getProperty("m3.appID"), iClientCredential).authority(AppInit.getProperty("m3.authority")).build();

        ClientCredentialParameters clientCredentialParameters = ClientCredentialParameters.builder(Collections.singleton(AppInit.getProperty("m3.scope"))).build();

        CompletableFuture<IAuthenticationResult> completableFuture = confidentialClientApplication.acquireToken(clientCredentialParameters);

        IAuthenticationResult iAuthenticationResult = completableFuture.get();

        getLogger().debug("Calling Azure Auth URL to get the token.");

        String token = iAuthenticationResult.accessToken();

        if (token == null || token.isEmpty()) {

            getLogger().info("Empty Token received.");

            throw new Exception("Unable to aquire token for Azure!");
        }

        getLogger().debug("Token Acquired.");

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        
        throw e;
    }

    // Set the token in the header.
    headers.put("Authorization", Collections.singletonList("Bearer " + token));

    getLogger().debug("Token Set in the request header.");

    getBindingProvider().getRequestContext().put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
}
```

The suggestion was to bypass the proxy that is used in the environment.

Can you please tell me how do I bypass the proxy in the Java Code? Any pointers would be helpful.